# Process VS Thread in commands Which runs first?

Tags: ubuntu, process, thread

I am wondering which would run or be created first on Linux if I were to run a command which uses both a process and a thread. I know they both use clone() to run and by definition a thread is basically a light process.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are part of a process, so OS will initiate processes before creating threads.

When you invoke a program, the OS does the following -

- loads code and data into memory
- creates and initializes process control block(PCB)
- creates the first thread with its call stack
- assigns initial values for "saved state" of the thread
- announces the thread to the dispatcher

*The dispatcher is the innermost part of the OS that runs on each core and controls the execution of processes and threads, based on a scheduling criterion.*

Dispatcher now -

- runs the thread for a while
- saves its state
- loads state of another thread
- executes that for a while..

OS uses interrupts/traps to gain control from the dispatcher. I've simplified the steps to help you understand better.